# how to stop backgound popup video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to all JS and i use Popup Magnific, i did a pop-up video, the problem is that it keeps running in the background after closing, i tried to do something to make it stop, but I got into trouble with it and i don't understand how to fix it.
i would love if anyone could help.

Attaching my code:

```js
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true,
  mainClass: 'custom-popup-class'
});

$("#popup").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#mpopup iframe").attr("video", $("#popup iframe").attr("video"));
    $.close function();
});
```

```css
.custom-popup-class .mfp-container {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.custom-popup-class .mfp-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
}

#popup1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

#popup1 .mfp-close {
  top: -47px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: right;
  right: 1px;
  font-size: 40px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="video-wrapper">
                          <div class="play">
                              <a href="#popup1" class="open-popup-link"><img src="img/3D/thumbnails/thumb1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                               <img src="img/play.png" class="play-btn"></a>
                                <div id="popup1" class="mfp-hide">
                                    <div class="box-video">
                                        <video source src="img/3D/videos/birthday1.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100%" controls preload></video>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have it so that when you click the button to close the window it would pause the video by adding a .pause(); , it would mean that you would need to .play(); to a play button if you wanted it to be re-playable in the future.  If you give the close button an ID as well as the video an ID it could work.

In vanilla JS rather than in jQuery you could use

```
document.getElementById("closeButtonID").addEventListener("click", function(event){
document.getElementById("videoID ").pause();
```

})

Then you would just need to add a similar 2 lines to to the above but instead add .play();
Hope this helps/works!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've lost you, can you explain another way? I don't control all js yet to do things you said.

Comment: You could add add something along the lines of this:  jQuery("Home Page class or ID").on('pageshow', function(event) { $('video').each(function () { // looks for all the videos open this.currentTime = 0; this.pause(); });

Comment: Sorry for the late response, all this time I tried to understand and do what you said, and without success.
Plus, when I added the bottom lines the popup stopped working (ן said before i didn't get along) I don't know anymore and how to do it.
It seems big to me to understand it and to do it.

Comment: there is video tutorial maybe that way i will understand how to do it in a simpler way?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJm-GFtlbMU  This video is about the basics of onclick events. Starting with the basics may help

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out now